# How can I filter data from a dataframe to show data between several datetimes from a different dataframe?

Tags: python

I want to filter df1 to only show data that is between the DatetimeStart and DatetimeEnd datetimes in df2.

df1

```
    Estimate    datetimeUTC
0   24.870665   2022-05-15 06:05:00+00:00
1   28.534566   2022-05-15 06:10:00+00:00
2   24.412932   2022-05-15 06:15:00+00:00
3   39.325210   2022-05-15 06:20:00+00:00
4   146.334005  2022-05-15 06:25:00+00:00
... ... ...
4286    1.604675    2022-07-24 05:35:00+00:00
4287    1.090453    2022-07-24 05:40:00+00:00
4288    0.747863    2022-07-24 05:45:00+00:00
4289    0.000000    2022-07-24 05:50:00+00:00
4290    0.000000    2022-07-24 05:55:00+00:00
```

df2

```
    DatetimeStart   DatetimeEnd meanKGH
0   2022-05-16 21:27:30.031000+00:00    2022-05-16 22:30:05.374000+00:00    2.558881
1   2022-05-17 14:05:41.241000+00:00    2022-05-17 17:19:46.208000+00:00    4.423160
2   2022-05-17 17:55:06.274000+00:00    2022-05-17 20:11:23.265000+00:00    4.435756
3   2022-05-17 20:40:24.169000+00:00    2022-05-17 22:46:46.491000+00:00    4.937177
4   2022-05-18 14:19:36.670000+00:00    2022-05-18 15:24:39.494000+00:00    1.490863
5   2022-05-18 15:34:29.384000+00:00    2022-05-18 16:39:24.150000+00:00    0.731882
6   2022-05-18 17:04:25.134000+00:00    2022-05-18 18:09:37.950000+00:00    3.623294
7   2022-05-18 18:49:55.826000+00:00    2022-05-18 19:52:34.110000+00:00    5.690513
8   2022-05-18 20:23:29.154000+00:00    2022-05-18 21:04:44.305000+00:00    11.824433
9   2022-05-18 21:44:16.175000+00:00    2022-05-18 22:44:41.218000+00:00    11.896398
10  2022-05-18 22:56:54.645000+00:00    2022-05-18 23:55:03.087000+00:00    4.003575
11  2022-05-19 14:15:19.518000+00:00    2022-05-19 18:24:34.936000+00:00    9.140599
12  2022-05-19 19:09:40.824000+00:00    2022-05-19 23:06:15.612000+00:00    9.136605
13  2022-05-20 13:28:52.073000+00:00    2022-05-20 15:31:54.219000+00:00    5.421379
14  2022-05-20 15:47:27.298000+00:00    2022-05-20 17:56:20.666000+00:00    1.422874
15  2022-07-18 14:27:59.238000+00:00    2022-07-18 16:59:48.325000+00:00    2.178103
16  2022-07-18 17:11:14.584000+00:00    2022-07-18 18:55:34.275000+00:00    2.964559
17  2022-07-18 19:23:23.860000+00:00    2022-07-18 21:23:59.641000+00:00    5.661950
18  2022-07-18 21:31:36.162000+00:00    2022-07-18 22:41:29.999000+00:00    8.059542
19  2022-07-19 13:18:58.930000+00:00    2022-07-19 15:00:55.187000+00:00    0.953863
20  2022-07-19 15:03:22.686000+00:00    2022-07-19 17:03:06.405000+00:00    11.836619
21  2022-07-20 13:44:33.822000+00:00    2022-07-20 15:59:30.456000+00:00    0.958181
22  2022-07-20 16:00:28.649000+00:00    2022-07-20 18:05:20.733000+00:00    5.560149
23  2022-07-20 18:06:02.896000+00:00    2022-07-20 20:00:05.697000+00:00    2.577347
24  2022-07-20 20:00:43.818000+00:00    2022-07-20 22:17:46.254000+00:00    14.638751
25  2022-07-21 13:57:41.194000+00:00    2022-07-21 16:01:36.047000+00:00    7.850944
26  2022-07-21 16:05:13.766000+00:00    2022-07-21 17:59:12.472000+00:00    0.977591
27  2022-07-21 18:00:02.641000+00:00    2022-07-21 20:09:59.584000+00:00    9.231221
28  2022-07-21 20:10:21.683000+00:00    2022-07-21 20:42:12.073000+00:00    17.146463
29  2022-07-21 20:44:47.577000+00:00    2022-07-21 22:25:56.725000+00:00    5.674103
30  2022-07-22 13:40:16.324000+00:00    2022-07-22 14:38:50.858000+00:00    16.757238
31  2022-07-22 14:41:54.427000+00:00    2022-07-22 15:46:33.143000+00:00    9.189459
32  2022-07-22 15:54:15.672000+00:00    2022-07-22 17:53:17.154000+00:00    3.150163
```

So far, I have tried this, but am only getting the df1 data for the last (id=32) date range in df2

```
    for i in range(len(df2)):
            t1 = df2.loc[i, 'DatetimeStart']
            t2 = df2.loc[i, 'DatetimeEnd']
            data = df1.loc[(df1['datetimeUTC'] >= t1) & (df1['datetimeUTC'] <= t2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

###### Create new dataframe

```
newdf=pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=df1.columns)
```

###### Then concatenate

```
for i in range(len(df2)):
    newdf=pd.concat([newdf,(df1[df1['datetimeUTC'].between(df2['DatetimeStart'][i],df2['DatetimeEnd'][i])])],ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This gives me the same output.
I only get data that is in the range of i = 32 in df2.

Comment: ah, i understand your question now, you need to concatenate. edited the response to show.

Comment: Thanks for the update...I receive a Keyerror: 33 with the change though.